# Change/access remote variable in remote process

Tags: julia, distributed-computing

I am new to Julia and trying to do a very simple task:

1. to distribute variable x=1 to every process
2. change x to a different value only in process 2 (change x local to process 2)
3. print the new value of remote x in process 2

My code is:

```
using Distributed
function f()
  x=10*x
  println(x)
end
@everywhere x=1
remote_do(f,2)
```

It does not print anything.
Another try with remotecall:

```
r=remotecall(x->10*x,2,x)
fetch(r)
println(x)
```

prints 10 (what anonymous function returns) and 1 (x in process 1) as expected.
As I understand `remotecall` returns a *future* with result of lambda x->10x but does not change the remote variable. In fact it even does not multiply the remote variable but x in process 1!

Question: How to change and read remote variable in process 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `x` is scoped locally to `f()`, so even running `f()` on the local process produces an error:

```
julia> f()
ERROR: UndefVarError: x not defined
```

If you really want to use a global variable here, you need to tell Julia that:

```
function f()
  global x=10*x
  println(x)
end

julia> f()
10
```

Then, to see why it isn't running remotely, you can try `remotecall_fetch` to make the call synchronously and see any exceptions (without this exceptions go to `stderr` on the remote worker).

```
julia> remotecall_fetch(f, 2)
ERROR: On worker 2:
UndefVarError: #f not defined
```

The remote worker does not have a definition for `f`.

```
@everywhere function f()
  global x=10*x
  println(x)
end

julia> remote_do(f,2)

julia>       From worker 2:     10
```

To make this easier when you have more code, you could place the code in a module and then call `@everywhere using MyModule`.

Comment: Thanks! This solves the question. I do the testing/learning on my multicore laptop, so there is not a real "remote" worker but all is on the local machine. You wrote "go to stdout on the remote worker" in case I use asynchronous call. How to see the stdout of a remote worker?

Comment: I made a mistake there, it is actually `stderr` see [the docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Distributed/#Distributed.remote_do-Tuple{Any,Integer,Vararg{Any,N}%20where%20N}). Unfortunately, that doesn't help much because I don't know where that output actually goes, sorry.